# VBScript Cannot Find file Specified Server 2003

Tags: excel, vbscript, outlook, windows-server-2003

I have the following code:

```
set app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb = app.Workbooks.Open("Y:\Billing_Common\autoemail\*.xls")

set sh = wb.Sheets("Auto Email Script")
row = 2
name = "Customer"
email = sh.Range("A" & row)
subject = "Billing"
the = "the"
LastRow = sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For r = row to LastRow
    If App.WorkSheetFunction.CountA(sh.Rows(r)) <> 0 Then 
        SendMessage email, name, subject, TRUE, _
        NULL, "Y:\Billing_Common\autoemail\Script\energia-logo.gif", 143,393
        row = row + 1
        email = sh.Range("A" & row)
    End if
Next
wb.close
set wb = nothing
set app = nothing


Sub SendMessage(EmailAddress, DisplayName, Subject, DisplayMsg, AttachmentPath, ImagePath, ImageHeight, ImageWidth)

  ' Create the Outlook session.
  Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

  template = FindTemplate()

  ' Create the message.
  Set objOutlookMsg  = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

  With objOutlookMsg
      ' Add the To recipient(s) to the message.
      Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add(EmailAddress)
      objOutlookRecip.resolve
      objOutlookRecip.Type = 1

     ' Set the Subject, Body, and Importance of the message.
     .Subject = Subject
     .bodyformat = 3
     .Importance = 2  'High importance

     body = Replace(template, "{First}", name)
     body = Replace(body, "{the}", the)

     if not isNull(ImagePath) then
       if not ImagePath = "" then
         .Attachments.add ImagePath
         image = split(ImagePath,"\")(ubound(split(ImagePath,"\")))
         body = Replace(body, "{image}", "<img src='cid:" & image & _
         "'" & " height=" & ImageHeight &" width=" & ImageWidth & ">")
       end if
     else
        body = Replace(body, "{image}", "")
     end if

     if not isNull(AttachMentPath) then
       .Attachments.add AttachmentPath
     end if

     .HTMLBody = body
         .Save
         .Send
    End With
    Set objOutlook = Nothing
End Sub

Function FindTemplate()
    Set OL = GetObject("", "Outlook.Application")
    set Drafts = OL.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(16)
    Set oItems = Drafts.Items

    For Each Draft In oItems
        If Draft.subject = "Template" Then
            FindTemplate = Draft.HTMLBody
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

It works fine when run off my local machine, but when run off Windows server it throws out an error at the line:

```
Set wb = app.Workbooks.Open("Y:\Billing_Common\autoemail\*.xls")
```

Saying it cannot find the file specified, the server has Office 2003 on it and I have ran out of ideas on why it's not working.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: is the `Y:` drive mapped on the server?

Comment: Yes, I've checked naming, spelling everything so confusing that it won't work on the server. I was thinking it wasnt compatible with 2003 as I have 2007 on my local PC

Comment: perhaps 2003 doesn't support the wildcard in your path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the `Open` method of Office 2003 doesn't support wildcards in the path. You'll have to enumerate the files in that folder:

```
Set app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For Each f In fso.GetFolder("Y:\Billing_Common\autoemail").Files
  If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(f)) = "xls" Then
    Set wb = app.Workbooks.Open(f.Path)
    ...
    wb.Close
  End If
Next
```

Comment: For a slightly more convenient alternative for enumerating files, Office 2003 still has the Application.FileSearch object (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa219847(v=office.11).aspx). This has been deprecated in Office 2007+, and partially replaced by the wildcard support in WorkBooks.Open et al.